# Windows gvim (74) syntax file, syntax not matching what it sould

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am trying to create a vim syntax file (actually for gvim, but they should be very similar), but one of my matching groups does not match what it should.

I need to match the literal "nop" or "NOP" and grey it out.
how I do this is:

```
syn match nopkw 'nop|NOP'
```

according to my own knowledge, and (more importantly) regex101.com, this should match literal "nop" or "NOP". Later in my file I use

```
highlight nopkw guifg=#d3d3d3
```

If I am correct, this should make all "nop"'s light grey. But it does not.
I have other matches in my file that work correctly, such as for numbers:

```
syn match num '\d+'
highlight num guifg=#ff0000
```

This works fine, as expected. Why does the "nop" regex not work, and can you find me one that does?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thankfully, the answer is really simple. You need to escape the bar for it work as an 'or'. Try this:

```
syn match nopkw 'nop\|NOP'
```

Or, another option would be to use the [magic option](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic). This would look like this:

```
syn match nopkw '\vnop|NOP'
```

Comment: thank you. Is there a list/artcle somewhere of how vim regex differs from regular regex?

Comment: @YourGamerMom Well, there isn't technically a *real* regex. There are many implementations, and they're all slightly different. However, I find myself *constantly* referencing [this page](http://vimregex.com/). Very useful!